# Записать текущую дату и время Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, mobile-development

Добрый день! Как в свифте "вычленить"текущую дату и время желательно в виде String, ну или Array на худой конец...

Comment: Точно должна быть такая функция!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"
let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: Date.init())
print(dateString)
```

Comment: Спасибо! Работает!